# Want to autofill the TextBoxes when the value is selected from the ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void vtype_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from vehicle_types where name = " + vtype.SelectedValue.ToString() + " ", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sda.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            dcharge.Text = dr["daily_charge"].ToString();
            wcharge.Text = dr["weekly_charge"].ToString();
            mcharge.Text = dr["monthly_charge"].ToString();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question or tell us the issue.  Use parameters to avoid sql injection and solve your immediate problem.

Comment: invalid column name error is coming when executing the code

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?